# Rails 4 How to find the categories with all expired products using an efficient query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, group-by, query-optimization

I am a beginner in RoR. I have two tables `Category` and `Product`. Each `Category` has many `Products`. We can get a Product's Category by `product.category_id`. Some products may not have any category. It will be `nil` in this case. We should omit these products with `category_id` as `nil`. There is a field in `Product` called `validity_time` with `datetime` as type. I need to find the categories in which all the products under the that category must have `validity_time` older than 1 month from now.(`< Time.now - 1.month`).
How to group the products by `category_id` and check the `validity_time` and return the resultant categories? What will the efficient query to do this?

---

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it, with inverted condition, i.e. no product in the category has a `validity_time` greater than one month before now:

```sql
select * from category
where not exists 
(
 select from product
 where product.category_id = category.id 
 and product.validity_time >= now() - interval '1 month'
)
```